# backslash inside double quotes in php string

Tags: php

this doesn't work because of the backslash inside the double quote

```
exec("convert $file -resize 100x100\> $destination");
```

I've tried inserting **{}** and **\** and even \\ with no success!

```
exec("convert $file -resize 100x100{\}> $destination"); //failed!
exec("convert $file -resize 100x100\\\> $destination"); //failed!
exec("convert $file -resize 100x100\\> $destination"); //failed!
```

I know i'm close, but i can't find it! What is it ??
Thanks

Comment: what makes you say it is the back slash ?

Comment: Why do you need the backslash? The redirection of output you seek is just the >

Comment: What is the original command you want to send to exec?

Comment: @karthikr because when i remove \> i can see the thumbnail being created and when it's there it creates an empty file  with no size and no dimensions... maybe i'm wrong...

Comment: @bitfiddler no redirection is wanted. `-resize` should receive a geometry argument of `100x100>`

Comment: @hobbs - He wants the output redirected to the file path in $destination

Comment: @bitfiddler sorry, wrong. ImageMagick doesn't write to stdout, it takes the output filename as an argument. `100x100>` is a geometry specifier that means "resize to 100x100, but do nothing if the source image was smaller than that".

Comment: the echo shows the right stuff: convert c:/fc_gallery/51d0c68f82141.jpeg -resize 100x100\> c:/public_html/gallery/images/51d0c68f82141_t.jpeg

Answer (score 1):

If you need to put a backslash inside a text, then you should write `\\`. Then you're writing a backslash (escape) and then writing a backslash.

Answer (score 1):

Quote the argument:

```
exec("convert $file -resize '100x100>' $destination");
```

Comment: @Marco: Sorry to hear it. What happened?

Answer (score 0):

If you really need the backslash, try something like this (with single quotes):

```
exec('convert '.$file.' -resize 100x100\> '.$destination);
```

Answer (score 0):

I replaced exec with echo to see what string you end up with:

```
$destination='something';
echo "convert $file -resize 100x100\\> $destination";
echo "<br>\n";
echo "convert $file -resize 100x100\\> $destination";
echo "<br>\n";
echo "convert $file -resize 100x100\\\> $destination";
```

output:

```
convert -resize 100x100\> something
convert -resize 100x100\> something
convert -resize 100x100\\> something
```

So the problem seems to be in the command itself.

I'd put the string together like this though:

`$ex_string='convert '.$file.' -resize 100x100\> '.$destination;`

Answer (score 0):

after many many testing and reading, i've found the solution for those that are interested

**test1**

```
$from = 'c:/fc_gallery/test.jpg'; //image size: 662 x 960
$to = 'c:/public_html/gallery/images/test.jpg';

exec("convert -resize 100x100 $from $to"); //produces a thumbnail of 62x100, keeps aspect ratio
```

**test2**

```
$from = 'c:/fc_gallery/test.jpg'; //image size: 1874 x 1430
$to = 'c:/public_html/gallery/images/test.jpg';

exec("convert -resize 100x100 $from $to"); //produces a thumbnail of 100x76, keeps aspect ratio
```

I was surprised that i didn't need the backslash(\) or the greater sign(>) to keep the aspect ratio!
I'm using imagemagick version 6.8.6-Q16... and, for those that are interested,i'm reading the book **The Definitive Guide To ImageMagick**

Comment: Yep, `-resize` keeps aspect ratio by default; `>` makes it not scale *up* if it’s smaller than both of those dimensions.